# Javascript upload file from web page to specific google drive account

Tags: javascript, file, authentication, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I'm developing an web application right now.

What I have so far in the app is this:

```
<input type="text" id="textToSendToMyGoogleDrive"/>
<button id="upload file to google drive"> Send </button>
```

This application has a domain, so every one can go to this application from their computer.

What I want to do is when any user put text in the input, and clicks the button, it will make a txt file and send it into my google drive account.

So I have two problems here:

1. How to take the text and make from it a txt file.
2. Send the file to specific google drive account.

Problem number 2 is a problem because I have looked every where in the google drive API, and all I could found is some methods to upload files to the user's google drive, and not to mine. So I tried to search out how to "sign in" the user when he is in the application to *my* google drive, and I could not find a solution.

If I was not clear on the problems, comment me.

Thank you!

Comment: what is the backend of your applcation? if you have one.

Comment: I do not have one.  Is it possible without it?

Comment: welcome to SO. You really need to read the Google documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk and then come back when you have more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not a expert but correct me if I'am wrong. I think there is a problem with your approach. how about sending your text content as a request parameter to the backend and save it as a .txt from there.

I am suggesting this because, 
let say you save your file with text content in users computer as described in [here](https://redstapler.co/generate-text-file-javascript/).

next step would be to access it from the browser and save it in the google drive. if you planning to do it from the front end without a backend, you have to expose your google credentials to every user.

Before that you wont be able to access a local file from users computer directly from the browser. because most browsers wont allow you to do that. so please change your approach to this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I did not understand something.
Why if it will expose my google account to every user?

Comment: normally in the backend what we do is, we use our refresh token(valid for 6 month or so) to generate a access token (short lived). then we send access token to user and he will upload a file using that token as a credential. if you were to generate access token from the front end( I am not sure you can do that) you must have the refresh token. refresh token is a sensitive information, you don't wont to expose that.

Comment: I got you. But could not I just hide this info from the front end? So no body can see it?

Comment: oh never do that buddy..! that is huge risk to take. where are you planing to host your application?

Comment: heroku support node.js right? you can use it for uploading part. use this link. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads